# Error or Error Code in case of PNS data expired or invalid

Tags: .net, azure, azure-hub

I'm using .Net assembly (dll) not Rest API.
**Question:** What would be the response/error status received  from MS Azure Notification Hub in below scenarios

a) When certificate become expired in MS Azure Hub.
b) When APNS certificate (which is existing in MS Azure Notification Hub) become invalid while sending notification.
c) When APNS Token (which is existing in MS Azure Notification Hub) become invalid while sending notification.
d) When GCM Api Key (which is existing in MS Azure Notification Hub) become invalid while sending Notification

Comment: Please edit your question and provide details of what you have tried so far

Comment: I have updated my question . Your assistance herein greatly appreciated.